# How do you explain Area 51 process to a layman?

Tags: discussion, area-51

I consider myself a huge movie buff. I have just committed to the [**Movies**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies) proposal. Also, I have been using Stack Overflow for quite some time so I know how Area 51 works.

When I told my friends (who too are movie fans) about [**Movies**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies) proposal, initially they were very interested and wanted to see the site. But when I tried to explain the site creation process and that it is not active as of now; that they would have to commit to it, it put them off. Frankly, people who like movies are generally not very technical. Don't get me wrong; they are experts in the field of movies but get scared by terms like Commit, Beta, Launch.

How do I explain Area 51 to them in simple terms so that they commit to the site and so that [**Movies**](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698/movies) sees the light of the day?

Comment: I've had this same problem trying to get people to join even osdev.se, (fellow programmers, but ones that don't use SO). Most people are confused by the entire process of site creation

Answer (score 2):

Simply tell them to get their friends to sign up and make it full.

Comment: The general perception of "signing up" is that to start using the site immediately. But in Area 51, you have to wait which people don't want to do. How to convince them?

Comment: @Mayank well tell them to get involed in other SE sites so that thy get more pc points.